# Word attachment file name prints as icon with ? inside when I print email

Tags: printing, file, attachments

I have a Mac with Word 2011.  Every now and then when I print an email with a Word attachment, my HP printer prints an icon with a question mark instead of the Word file name.

Comment: To clarify, you are printing a Word Document that was attached in email, not the email it self.

Comment: Could you give us an example of a filename that doesn't print and one that does?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with a MacPro Yosemite and an old hp printer. At least you can get it to display properly in your and the recipient's computer though not to print properly.

Go to Mail Preferences - Accounts - Advanced and uncheck "automatically detect and maintain mail settings"